# Why use date constructor function for creating date object?

Tags: javascript

if date object is builtin object in javascript then why we create date object 
with date constructor function. because object constructor function is used when we create multiple objects of same type..?

Comment: Please show as code what do you mean with `date constructor function`  and how would you expect that a date is created without this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no *"date literal"* syntax in JS, so that leaves you with functions as the means of creating `Date` objects.

I don't know what you mean by calling a date a "builtin object". It's a native object type to the ECMAScript environment, but that doesn't automatically mean that they shouldn't be created using a constructor function.

Comment: Why we didn't use date object as math object , without using the date () constructor

Comment: `Math` doesn't create anything. It's just an object to store math utility functions. You could put a function on a `Date` object to create date objects, but that function would still be a constructor function, just in a different location.